# Caching information with timeout

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm looking for a way to do caching but I want the information to only stay in memory for a period of time (web and winform).

Is there a built-in .net library that allows caching with a timeout? Similar to the session variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. Generic caching tools are available with .NET 4.0 in the `System.Runtime.Caching` namespace.

More information:

- [Caching in .NET Framework Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997357%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

For your use case, it sounds like the [MemoryCache class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) would be an appropriate solution.